# Fossil: how to display checked in image files on wiki pages?

Tags: version-control, fossil

Here is the complete workflow:

Initialize the repository and the workspace

```
$ fossil new repo.fossil
$ mkdir workspace
$ cd workspace
$ fossil open ../repo.fossil
```

Add an image file to the repository

```
$ fossil add image.jpg
$ fossil commit -m "added image.jpg"
```

Start fossil server:

```
$ fossil server
```

Open the web interface in the browser:

```
BROWSERNAME 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Now I'd like to get image.jpg displayed in a wiki page.

Things I've tried:

```
[image.jpg]
<img src="image.jpg">
```

I've also tried to toggle the "Use HTML as wiki markup language" in Admin->Configuration

Comment: Note that `fossil ui` is a shortcut for `fossil server` and launching your browser. It will also get the port number right if something else is already using port 8080.

Answer (score 7):

see [this page](http://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/doc/tip/www/embeddeddoc.wiki). You should use `<img src='/doc/tip/image.jpg'/>` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, though through a roundabout process.

Once you've checked in an image, find it in the Files section of your "fossil ui", click it, and see that it displays the image there for you.  From there, you can take the URL of that image (in Chrome, right-click it, "Copy image URL".  In my test, that URL was `http://localhost:8081/raw/2c2e13a1f71295c3?m=image/jpeg`

Then edit your wiki page and add, for example:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8081/raw/2c2e13a1f71295c3?m=image/jpeg"/>
```

Comment: A slightly better way to do this is to use a relative link so that if the domain name changes the links will still work.  

<img src="/raw/2c2e13a1f71295c3?m=image/jpeg"/>

You can  also do this with markdown links, eg:

![](/raw/37e10bc7c5e3b1bb47ec60903bf7d9ee71d1ad0e6fd525b0865eb3bad51c622e?m=image/png)